# MySQL Query - Use Self Join To Find Rows Closest To Start and End Dates

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query that is using one table to find the `revenue` column for a list of account numbers closest to either end of a date range, i.e. the row closest to the start of a date range, and the one closest to the end.

I've came up with the following but it only seems to work for the first account number and not any others after that.

```
SELECT a.acct_no,
b.revenue AS first_value, b.created_at AS first_date,
c.revenue AS second_value, c.created_at AS second_date

FROM `revenue_figures` a

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `acct_no`, `revenue`, `created_at`
    FROM  `revenue_figures`
    WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2017-02-28 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-31 23:59:59'
    AND `acct_no` IN ('A123', 'A124')
    GROUP BY `acct_no`, `revenue`, `created_at`
    ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
    LIMIT 1
) b ON a.acct_no = b.acct_no

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `acct_no`, `revenue`, `created_at`
    FROM  `revenue_figures`
    WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2017-02-28 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-31 23:59:59'
    AND `acct_no` IN ('A123', 'A124')
    GROUP BY `acct_no`, `revenue`, `created_at`
    ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
    LIMIT 1
) c ON a.acct_no = c.acct_no

WHERE a.`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-02-28 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-31 
23:59:59'
AND a.`acct_no` IN ('A123', 'A124')

GROUP BY a.acct_no, first_value, first_date, second_value, second_date
```

This produces the following, but there are figures in the table for the `A124` account number:

```
acct_no first_value first_date  second_value    second_date
A123    8990.00     2017-02-28  7364.80         2017-03-31 01:00:00
A124    NULL        NULL        NULL            NULL
```

I think there is a fundamental flaw with the query as I noticed that if I run it a few times, I can generate different results, such as:

```
acct_no first_value first_date  second_value    second_date
A123    8990.00     2017-02-28  NULL            NULL
A124    NULL        NULL        28361.76        2017-03-31 01:00:00
```

**Table Structure**

```
id, acct_no, revenue, created_at
```

**Example Data**

```
1, A123, 8990.00, 2017-02-28 01:00:00
2, A123, 7364.80, 2017-03-31 01:00:00
3, A124, 17324.12, 2017-02-28 01:00:00
4, A124, 28361.76, 2017-03-31 01:00:00
```

Comment: You should share your table structure(s) and example data... we can't answer your question with only a query.

Comment: Hi Raymond, added some example data, not actual `CREATE` or `INSERT` statements though.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` means you only get one row in each subquery. If the row is for `A123`, you won't get any data for `A124`. It's not one row per account.

Comment: If you want to get the oldest and newest rows for each account, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1

Comment: thanks, will have a look. If I take out the `LIMIT 1` from the subqueries, I then end up with a result for every day per account number within the date range which is the problem.

Comment: Get rid of the _inner_ `GROUP BYs` -- it is doing nothing useful, and it is slowing the query down.

Comment: Don't call then "second_value" and "second_date"; call them "last_value" and "last_date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reopened because the OP's code handles what the "dup" question discussed.  The real question is about another issue.)

The problem is that you ask for the latest of two `acct_nos`, but then `LIMIT 1`, which throws out one of them.  Let's start by focusing on one subquery.

Am I correct in saying that you want 2 rows, one per acct_no?  To do so, you need to look for 1 row for each acct_no.  And probably the only way to do that is with a `UNION ALL` of two `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`.  No `GROUP BY`.

So, now you have

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    ( SELECT ... acct_no = 'A123' ... LIMIT 1 )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT ... acct_no = 'A124' ... LIMIT 1 )
)
```

*First* debut the UNION to see if it gets the desire pair of rows.

*Then* put it into each `LEFT JOIN` (though I don't know if you need `LEFT`) to see if the big query comes out OK.

Some other tips...

```
INDEX(acct_no, created_at)
```

Use this pattern:

```
    created_at >= '2017-03-01'
AND created_at  < '2017-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

What you have includes the last day of Feb, plus all of Mar; was that deliberate?  And, is `created_at` a `DATETIME`?  Or some other datatype?

The *outer* `GROUP BY` should be just

```
GROUP BY acct_no
```

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for re-opening and for the answer. `created_at` is a `TIMESTAMP` column. The dates were intentional as it's a date range entered from the front-end, so the plan was to find the rows closest to either end of the date range. Will give this a try in work tomorrow, managed to get it working by querying for the exact date but would rather have it work as originally intended.